# JetBrains IDE - Inspection - How to globally change error severity?

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Particularly I use PyCharm and need to change `Class must implements all abstract methods` inspection to be error, so all files with such error should be underlined in red.

Sadly, when I'm trying to do it by [conventional way](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/customizing-profiles.html) it changes error level only for my manual scans and editor, but not for files window. Also if I try to select this error 'in inspection results' and click 'Run inspection on' - then results of this run will be default too.

Comment: Possibly you are using different profile in another place? Although, currently selected profile should be used. Have you tried changing the severity for that inspection in ALL profiles?

Comment: Trying to make it in default(one and only) profile is first thing i did.